# Can't restore Windows 8 after installing xubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, windows-8, uefi

Got a new Lenovo G710 with Windows 8 on it. Followed the directions to install Xubuntu. Now I have a boot loader menu, but when I select the Windows item in it, Windows fails to boot. I read about boot-repair, but when I run it, it told me that I need to use boot repair 64. So I downloaded the boot repair 64 ISO from Sourceforge and created a USB bootable from it using unetbootin. But the USB doesn't boot - it takes me straight back to the hard disk boot loader. It's not a BIOS issue because I used that same USB boot to install Xubuntu in the first place. Now I can't get back to Windows.

I used boot repair to create a log file to post to the forum, and it's [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8422824/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have windows 8 CD than you can recover your windows.

for this you have to follow this steps.

Boot from the Windows install or repair CD appropriate to you version of Windows.

**For Windows 8:**

1 – Boot from repair disc > Choose Keyboard type > click Troubleshoot > click Advanced options > choose Automatic Repair
if that fails then use:
2 -Boot from Recovery disc or Install disc

-Boot from repair disc > Chose Keyboard type > click Troubleshoot > click Advanced options > choose Command Prompt

or

-Boot from Install disc > Click Next > click Repair your computer > click Troubleshoot > click Advanced options > choose Command Prompt

type > bootrec /fixmbr (writes mbr but does not overwrite partition table)

type > bootrec /fixboot (writes new boot sector to system partition)

type > bootrec /scanos (scans for other OS’s that you might want to add to bcd)

(personally I find the above unneeded and only use the last step)

type > bootrec /rebuildbcd (scans for other OS’s, unlike rebuildbcd it allows you to select the OS’s you want to add to bcd)

Reboot

i hope that will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Two problems, though: I don't have a Windows CD, but also, I'd like to run this dual boot for Windows and Xubuntu. Is that not possible?

Comment: you have any windows iso image than you can create bootable USB from also you can recover.

Comment: please mark answer as correct if its help full to you

Comment: can I create a bootable USB from another Windows machine? Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: if someone having windows image (iso file) than you can create bootable USB from that pc/laptop.